# media9 in beamer: Fade-out audio on click

Tags: beamer, media9

I'm creating beamer presentation with some audio - one song per slide. The records fade in (this effect is created in external tool) and now I need to make them **fade out** and move to next slide on a single click.

I'm using `media9` package and this piece of code:

```
\begin{frame}{frame with sound \includemedia[
  label=my_sound,
  activate=pageopen, deactivate=pageclose,
  addresource=test.mp3,
  flashvars={
    source=test.mp3
    &autoPlay=true
    &hideBar=true
  },
  ]{}{APlayer.swf}}
  \dots
\end{frame}
```